# Change labels of grid in .net core WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a Grid on the UI that displays data(as shown in the picture and the code below), I want to change the labels of "novoIme", "staroIme", "naselenoMesto" and "opstina" into some cyrillic names. I tried something like adding [Display(Name = "...")] in the Model where the properties are declared, but it doesn't work like that. I'm new in WPF so any ideas or suggestions will be very much welcomed. :)

This is the button created in XAML:

```
<Button Name="UlicaStaraNova"  Grid.Row="1" Content="Листа на стари и нови имиња на улици" Margin="10,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.806,0.461" Click="UlicaStaraNova_Click"   />
```

This is the function that gets called once I click on the Button:

```
private void UlicaStaraNova_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid gridView = new DataGrid();
            gridView.Name = "gridViewUSN";
            gridView.ItemsSource = ListUlicaStaraNova;
            Window window = new Window();
            window.Content = gridView;
            window.Width = 670;
            window.Height = 700;
            window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            window.Show();
        }
```

This is the window that displays on the UI once the button is clicked:

[image]

Comment: It is better define DataGrid in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

**Or you could use Grid only. Here's the code if it helps,**

```
private void UlicaStaraNova_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid gridView = new Grid();
            gridView.ColumnList = new List<GridColumn>
            {
                new GridColumn("col1","col1","",""),
                new GridColumn("col2","col2","","")
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
gridView.Columns[0].Header="name";
gridView.Columns[1].Header="age";
```

or define in XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="griVeiw">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header = "name" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header = "age" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```